# Multiple aChartEngine Charts not scrolling

Tags: android, achartengine

I've been trying to display multiple charts in one activity. Currently, the first chart displays but the second does not (or maybe just can't be scrolled to). If I remove android:fillViewport="true" from the ScrollView then nothing displays. I modified the demo aChartEngine code to return a View instead of an intent. I don't know if the error is in XML, my custom Chart class, or my Activity. I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearParent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chartOne"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chartTwo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Activity:

```
    //setup Views
    myWindow = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paidLayoutLinearParent);
    row1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.paidLayoutChartOne);
    row2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.paidLayoutChartTwo);

    //Pie Charts
    pie = new PieChartView(this,dens);
    pieTotalCases = pie.getPieChart("Cases", gameStatsDb.getNumCasesPassed(), gameStatsDb.getNumCasesFailed());
    pieTotalCombos = pie.getPieChart("Combos", gameStatsDb.getNumCombosPassed(), gameStatsDb.getNumCombosFailed());

    //add charts to layout
    row1.addView(pieTotalCases,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    row2.addView(pieTotalCombos,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Custom PieChartView

```
public class PieChartView{
/** Colors to be used for the pie slices. */
  private static int[] COLORS = new int[] { Color.GREEN, Color.RED,Color.BLACK,Color.LTGRAY };
  private CategorySeries mSeries;
  private DefaultRenderer mRenderer;
  private Context myContext;
  float screenDens;

  public PieChartView(Context ctx,float screenDensity){
    myContext=ctx;
    screenDens=screenDensity;
  }

  public GraphicalView getPieChart(String title,int numPassed,int numFailed){
      mSeries = new CategorySeries("");
      mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
      stylizeChart();

      GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(myContext, mSeries, mRenderer);
      mRenderer.setChartTitle(title);
      if(numPassed==0 & numFailed==0){
          mSeries.add("None ",1);
          SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
          renderer.setColor(COLORS[3]);
          mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
          mRenderer.setDisplayValues(false);
          mRenderer.setStartAngle(90);
      }else{
          mSeries.add("Passed ",numPassed);
          SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
          renderer.setColor(COLORS[0]);
          mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

          mSeries.add("Failed ", numFailed);
          SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
          renderer2.setColor(COLORS[1]);
          mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
      }
          return mChartView;
  }

  private void stylizeChart(){
    //stylize chart
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
        mRenderer.setStartAngle(180);
        mRenderer.setDisplayValues(true);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);

        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(22*screenDens);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(17*screenDens);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(COLORS[2]);
        mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);

        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setZoomRate(6.0f);
        mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRy this xml (give some height to graph containers)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/graphHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#a11111"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/graphHolder2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#ea1111"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wow this makes a lot of sense, as aChartEngine defaults to width/height of fill_parent, and the linearLayout here is wrap_content. I'll try this later today, thank you!!!!

Comment: Thanks @James for your question and keshav for the answer. It helped me solve the same issue I was having